# How to solve java jar file exception ( version `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by libvlog-core.so) )?

Tags: apt, java, curl, jar

I am running a java jar file on my server (ubuntu)

I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: while loading vlog-core: /tmp/VLog-tmp/libvlog-core.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_4' not found (required by /tmp/VLog-tmp/libvlog-core.so)
```

when I run the command `curl --version` it return:

```
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
```

when I run the command `openssl version` it return:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Where is my problem? what I need to do to run this java jar file?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? On my system (based on Ubuntu 20), I have `curl 7.68.0` and the `libcurl4` package installed.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04.6

Comment: In that case, you may have to build the latest curl (and its libraries) yourself. What's weird is that this search on **Ubuntu Packages** - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libcurl4&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all - actually finds some libcurl4 packages for Xenial, but not the actual libcurl4 library.

Comment: How could I build the latest curl?

Comment: Here's the `curl` build/install guide: https://curl.se/docs/install.html.